# Catching failed email recipients in Laravel 9 (Symfony Mailer)

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-9, symfony-mailer

I have recently upgraded my Laravel application from **5.8 to 9.x**. In the previous version of Laravel, mail transport was done by **SwiftMailer**. But now in Laravel 9, it uses **SymfonyMailer**.

To get the failed recipient list, `Mail::failures()` was used, which returned an array of email addresses. In **Laravel 9**, this method is not available.

Is there any way to get the array of failed recipients?

Answer (score 2):

Does this helps, https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#handling-sending-failures

Symfony Mailer considers that sending was successful when your transport (SMTP server or third-party provider) accepts the mail for further delivery. The message can later be lost or not delivered because of some problem in your provider, but that's **out of reach for your Symfony application**.

If there's an error when handing over the email to your transport, Symfony throws a TransportExceptionInterface. Catch that exception to recover from the error or to display some message:

```
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;

$email = new Email();
// ...
try {
    $mailer->send($email);
} catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
    // some error prevented the email sending; display an
    // error message or try to resend the message
}
```

Comment: In others words, there is no need to check the failed recipients anymore ?